# Owl Carrousel with Swapping multiple div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, swap, owl-carousel

I am trying to achieve "a div always swap to next div on clicking a button named "***Vote Now***" in owl carousel" but it only one time swap accurate to next div on clicking the button other time it does not swap accurate to next div here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yajuvendra1990/b8qx6jjt/6/) link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        $(".go-swap").click(function() {            
            $("#currnt").swap({
                target: "next",
                opacity: "0.5",
                speed: 1000,                    
            });         
        });         
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        $('.item').hover(function(){ 
            $(this).attr('id', 'currnt'); 
            $(this).parent().prev().children().attr('id', 'next')},                 
            function(){
                $(this).attr('id', '');
                $(this).parent().prev().children().attr('id', '') 
            });
        }); 
</script>
<section id="demos">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item" data-hash="zero">
          <h4>0</h4>
            <a href="javascript://" class="go-swap"><button>Vote Now</button></a>
        </div>

        <div class="item" data-hash="one">
          <h4>1</h4>
            <a href="javascript://" class="go-swap"><button>Vote Now</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-hash="two">
          <h4>2</h4>
            <a href="javascript://" class="go-swap"><button>Vote Now</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-hash="three">
          <h4>3</h4>
            <a href="javascript://" class="go-swap"><button>Vote Now</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-hash="four">
          <h4>4</h4>
            <a href="javascript://" class="go-swap"><button>Vote Now</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//swap to next div

        var animating = false;

        $('.owl-carousel').on('click', '.swap', function() {

        var clickedDiv = $(this).closest('.owl-item'),

        prevDiv = clickedDiv.prev(),
        distance = clickedDiv.offset().left - prevDiv.offset().left;

          if (prevDiv.length) {
            animating = true;
            $.when(clickedDiv.animate({
                left: -distance
              }, 1000),
              prevDiv.animate({
                left: distance
              }, 1000)).done(function() {
              prevDiv.css('left', '0px');
              clickedDiv.css('left', '0px');
              clickedDiv.insertBefore(prevDiv);
              animating = false;
            });
            }
            });

// owl carousel
$(document).ready(function() {
 var slider = $('.owl-carousel');
  slider.owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    loop: false,
    center: false,
    margin: 10,
    callbacks: true,
    URLhashListener: true,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    startPosition: 'URLHash',
  touchDrag: false,
  mouseDrag: false
  });
  $(".swap").click(function() {
        slider.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
  });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yajuvendra1990/b8qx6jjt/9/

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, you can move to the next slide on click like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var slider =  $('.owl-carousel')

    slider.owlCarousel({
        items: 4,
        loop: false,
        center: false,
        margin: 10,
        callbacks: true,
        URLhashListener: true,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        startPosition: 'URLHash'
      });

     $(".go-swap").click(function() {
            slider.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
      });

});
```

fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Miraidev/uu8ukac6/

Is this what yo were looking for?

Comment: thanks for your answer but I want to when I click on Vote Now button it **swap** to the next div  please have a look my fiddle

Comment: Hi @Jim-miraidev, I have got the solution and updated my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yajuvendra1990/b8qx6jjt/9/) but there is one issue when I click on 2nd **DOT** and click on 4th position of "Vote Now" button it swap to 3rd position of slide, its ok. But 4th position of slide goes hidden I want to its just scroll one slide backward and also visible 4th position of slide. Can you help me?